# LIKE operator slowing down query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a more efficient way to filter the `LEDGERACCOUNT` column than with a `LIKE` operator? I need to sum the `TRANSACTIONCURRENCYAMOUNT` column when the `LEDGERACCOUNT` column begins with each account #. This slows down the rest of my query. I am trying to join with two other tables.

```
LEDGERACCOUNT
213510-LTL
305100-CORP
441230-SAA
441230-GODP
```

```
select g.ACCOUNTINGDATE,
   sum(case when g.LEDGERACCOUNT like '213510%'
            then convert(float, g.TRANSACTIONCURRENCYAMOUNT)
       else 0 end) as [113510-GL Transfer],
   sum(case when g.LEDGERACCOUNT like '305100%'
            then convert(float, g.TRANSACTIONCURRENCYAMOUNT)
            else 0
       end) as [205100-GL Transfer],
   sum(case when g.LEDGERACCOUNT like '441230%'
            then convert(float, g.TRANSACTIONCURRENCYAMOUNT)
            else 0
       end) as [241230-GL Transfer],
   sum(case when g.LEDGERACCOUNT not like '213510%'
                 or g.LEDGERACCOUNT not like '305100%'
                 or g.LEDGERACCOUNT not like '441230%'
            then convert(float, g.TRANSACTIONCURRENCYAMOUNT)
            else 0
       end) as [Other-GL Transfer]
from [AX2cTestStage].[dbo].[GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY_V] g
group by g.ACCOUNTINGDATE
order by g.ACCOUNTINGDATE
```

Comment: I doubt the `LIKE` is having much impact on performance.  The aggregation and sorting are probably slowing things down.

Comment: If GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY_V  is a view, then the Efficiency of Query in the view may also affect, other than the above mentioned aggregation and sorting. You can experiment by removing the order by part, removing the 4th Sum() portion whether those impacts.

Comment: Posting the query plan (search Paste the Plan) will be helpful here, along with the definition of object, if it is a `VIEW`.

Comment: Just a side note, I would change your OR 's to AND 's

Comment: `when g.LEDGERACCOUNT not like '213510%' or g.LEDGERACCOUNT not like '305100%' or g.LEDGERACCOUNT not like '441230%'` will **always** evaluate to true (well, maybe not with nulls).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For general ledge reporting you're better off creating separate columns for each component of the GL code. For example, in my last company the GL codes were [line of business]-[region]-[department]. By storing each separately I could easily run reports by LoB, region, dept, or any combination. Of course, that's only possible if you control the database and can add columns. Another possibility is to add them as computed columns in the view, which will really help if it's a materialized view.

Answer (score 0):

The only real thought I have for you to try is to use `left` (or, I suppose, `substring`) instead of `like`.  I'm not really sure it'll improve performance, but it's worth trying, I think.

**everything is untested**

```
select g.ACCOUNTINGDATE,
   sum(case when left(g.LEDGERACCOUNT, 6) = '213510'
            then convert(float, g.TRANSACTIONCURRENCYAMOUNT)
       else 0 end) as [113510-GL Transfer],
   sum(case when left(g.LEDGERACCOUNT, 6) = '305100'
            then convert(float, g.TRANSACTIONCURRENCYAMOUNT)
            else 0
       end) as [205100-GL Transfer],
   sum(case when left(g.LEDGERACCOUNT, 6) = '441230'
            then convert(float, g.TRANSACTIONCURRENCYAMOUNT)
            else 0
       end) as [241230-GL Transfer],
   sum(case when left(g.LEDGERACCOUNT, 6) not in ('213510', '305100', '441230')
            then convert(float, g.TRANSACTIONCURRENCYAMOUNT)
            else 0
       end) as [Other-GL Transfer]
from [AX2cTestStage].[dbo].[GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY_V] g
group by g.ACCOUNTINGDATE
order by g.ACCOUNTINGDATE
```

*Note the `Other-GL Transfer` logic is different from your original query, but I think this is what you're actually trying to accomplish.*

Another idea is to put in in the group by.

Note -- *this provides the data in rows instead of columns*  Mostly just providing this in case it sparks an idea for you.

```
select case when left(g.LEDGERACCOUNT, 6) in ('213510', '305100', '441230')
            then left(g.LEDGERACCOUNT, 6)
            else 'Other'
       end as ShortLedgerAcct,
   g.ACCOUNTINGDATE,
   sum(convert(float, g.TRANSACTIONCURRENCYAMOUNT) as TransferAmount
from [AX2cTestStage].[dbo].[GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY_V] g
group by g.ACCOUNTINGDATE,
   case when left(g.LEDGERACCOUNT, 6) in ('213510', '305100', '441230')
        then left(g.LEDGERACCOUNT, 6)
        else 'Other'
   end
order by g.ACCOUNTINGDATE
```

Finally, you could use `cross apply` which I doubt will provide a significantly different execution plan but some people find it prettier:

```
select g.ACCOUNTINGDATE,
   sum(case when ca.ShortLedgerAcct = '213510'
            then convert(float, g.TRANSACTIONCURRENCYAMOUNT)
       else 0 end) as [113510-GL Transfer],
   sum(case when ca.ShortLedgerAcct = '305100'
            then convert(float, g.TRANSACTIONCURRENCYAMOUNT)
            else 0
       end) as [205100-GL Transfer],
   sum(case when ca.ShortLedgerAcct = '441230'
            then convert(float, g.TRANSACTIONCURRENCYAMOUNT)
            else 0
       end) as [241230-GL Transfer],
   sum(case when ca.ShortLedgerAcct = 'Other'
            then convert(float, g.TRANSACTIONCURRENCYAMOUNT)
            else 0
       end) as [Other-GL Transfer]
from [AX2cTestStage].[dbo].[GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY_V] g
cross apply (
   select case when left(g.LEDGERACCOUNT, 6) in ('213510', '305100', '441230')
               then left(g.LEDGERACCOUNT, 6)
               else 'Other'
          end ShortLedgerAcct
) ca
group by g.ACCOUNTINGDATE
order by g.ACCOUNTINGDATE
```